# Conditional Data Annotation and dropdown viewmodel not validating properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have these viewmodels that I have combined to be used in a form. However When I validate the form and leave the Email, PhoneNumber and Method dropdown list blank, no validation appear and the ModelState is valid in the debug section.

The dropdown list doesn't seem to return any validation errors as well for some reason. When I debug, the input is null which is on purpose but it doesn't show any errors back

These are the viewmodels:

```
public class UnsubscribeContactDetailsViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class MethodsDropdownListViewModel
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Methods { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterUnsubscribeViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public UnsubscribeContactDetailsViewModel ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public MethodsDropdownListViewModel MethodsDropdownList { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactDetails.Email) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactDetails.PhoneNumber))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Either Email or Phone Number is required");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactDetails.Email) method instead of your current code

Comment: Please check and let me know

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. It doesn't work.

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace is an improvement over string.IsNullOrEmpty, so using the latter will not improve the validation process.

Comment: Can you show the code for the Action? Also, have you added a break point on the if condition and see if your code is hitting this line? I tried to replicate a more simpler implementation of your code and it seems to work on my end.